# Do atomic operations have memory order issues?

Tags: gcc, memory, atomic, memory-barriers

Are there `happens before` relationships between atomic operations, e.g. memory orders are required for atomics too？ For code:

```cpp
static int zero = 0;

static int proc_enter(struct proc_context* ctx, struct lkf_node* node)
{
    __atomic_store_n(&node->next, NULL, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);  // 0
    __atomic_store_n(&ctx->list.tail, &node->next, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);  // 1


    int n = (int) __atomic_compare_exchange_n(&ctx->stat, &zero, 1, false, __ATOMIC_RELEASE, // 2
                                              __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    return n - 1;
}

static int proc_leave(struct proc_context* ctx)
{
    __atomic_store_n(&ctx->stat, 0, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);  // 3

    __atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL); // 4

    if (__atomic_load_n(&ctx->list.tail, __ATOMIC_RELAXED) == &ctx->list.root.next) { // 5
        return 0;
    }

    int n = (int) __atomic_compare_exchange_n(&ctx->stat, &zero, 1, false, __ATOMIC_RELAXED,
                                              __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    return n - 1;
}
```

A couple of questions：

1. does __ATOMIC_RELEASE is required to guarantee `// 0` happening before `// 1`？
2. does __ATOMIC_RELEASE in __atomic_compare_exchange_n is required to guarantee `// 1` happening before `// 2`？
3. does __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL is required to guarantee `// 5` happening before `// 3`
4. Is __atomic_thread_fence is the only way to guarantee `// 5` happening before `// 3` (If it works)?

For the last question, my underlying logic is that(from cpu load-store queue):

1. write ctx->stat
2. flush store queue
3. flush load queue
4. load ctx->list.tail

`step 3` forbids `step 4` from hoisting and `step 2` forbids `step 1` from descending

Comment: To discuss anything about _guarantees_, you must specify exactly what compiler and target architecture you're using. These identifiers are by definition reserved words, and as such this code is only valid in the context of a C language implementation.

Comment: @paddy: These are GNU C builtins.  Like in their previous question ([Is there a meaning for \_\_atomic\_signal\_fence(\_\_ATOMIC\_RELAXED)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/133971031)), for some reason they're asking about these builtins instead of the C++ things that G++ implements in terms of these.

Comment: `// 5` is sequenced after `// 3`, so `3` happens-before `5` in that thread.  Did you really mean 5 before 3?  Perhaps you wanted to ask if `__atomic_thread_fence(__ATOMIC_ACQ_REL); // 4` can guarantee that `3` happens-before something in another thread?  acq_rel doesn't prevent store-load ordering.  (on x86 for example, there's no mfence or locked instruction).  A `seq_cst` fence could work, or making both operations `seq_cst`.

Comment: `proc_enter` store `ctx->list.tail` before __atomic_compare_exchange_n, `proc_leave` store `ctx->stat` (which affects `__atomic_compare_exchange_n` in `proc_enter`), then load `ctx->list.tail`(which affected by `proc_enter`), I want to keep the executing order, While if for example `proc_leave` executes like `void* pptr = __atomic_load_n(&ctx->list.tail, __ATOMIC_RELAXED); __atomic_store_n(&ctx->stat, 0, __ATOMIC_RELAXED); if (pptr == &ctx->list.root.next) {return 0;} ...`, logic is corrupted. I need find a way to prevent this

Comment: For a CPU with independent load-queue and store-queue, it seems load a;load(&b, acquire);load c; take effect by load a,b(without order);flush load-queue;load c; so loading c is guarantee after a,b; And store a;store(&b, release);store c, should same with store a;flush store-queue;strore b,c(without order).